# Empty response when startindex >= 100

Tags: youtube-api

After a lot of debugging, it finally occured to me that seemingly Youtube is only issueing the first 100 comments when using the v2 YouTube-API for getting comments. I finally tried using:

```
curl -Lk -X GET "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MShbP3OpASA/comments?alt=json&start-index=100&max-results=50"
```

And all I get is a response without an `entry` parameter. That is to say, I do not receive an error response or something like that - I get a perfectly good response, but without the `entry` parameter.

Digging a little deeper, in my response the value for `openSearch$totalResults` is 100, so in accordance to [this resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?csw=1#Paging_through_Results) this seems to be the expected result (although it tells about some kind of error message which I don't get?).

But here comes the kicker: When I use

```
curl -Lk -X GET "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MShbP3OpASA/comments?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&orderby=published"
```

`openSearch$totalResults` equals 3141, the actual count of the comments.

Now here is my question: Since the v2 API is officially been deprecated about a week ago, is it possible that Google just set up a limit on the comments? So only the first 100 comments are accessible? Since the v3 API does not allow for comment retrieval, that would be a pretty bummer for me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find out an answer to this? It's happening to me, too.

Comment: @sean-anderson No. There is a bug report on gdata-issues however: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5583 no response there... Right now I am waiting for Google to update their v3 api to incorporate comments or similar. I have the impression that they are deliberately blocking the query of >100 comments in accordance to the deprecation of v2.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that I stayed up late re-writing a v2 request as a v3 and it experienced the same issue after requesting the third batch of 50 videos via nextPageToken. I'm not certain it's a v2 issue. :(

Comment: I wasn't even aware that one can pull comments of a video with v3. Can you share your script?

Comment: Ahh. I wasn't pulling comments. I was pulling video information for a playlist, but the playlist's length exceeded 100 videos. I was only able to retrieve the first 100.

Comment: I understand stopping support for v2 in favour of v3 as we all need to move forward, but changing and/or removing functionality from something that potentially millions rely on ( me included ) is not a good move.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out how to retrieve all the comments using the navigation links embedded in the json response.

Suppose you retrieve the first using a link like (python here, but you get the point):

r'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + aVideoID + r'/comments?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true&orderby=published'

Embedded in the json under "feed" (and before the comments) will be a four element array called "link". The fourth element will be called "rel": "next" and under "href" there will be a link you can use to get the next 50 comments. The link will look something like:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fH0cEP0mvlU/comments?alt=json&orderby=published&alt=json&start-token=EgkI2NqyoZDRvgIosK%2FPosPRvgIw653cmsXRvgI4AUAC&max-results=50&orderby=published

for an original URL of:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fH0cEP0mvlU/comments?alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true&orderby=published

If you follow the next link it will return similar json to the original link, with another 50 comments. Continue this process over and over until you get all the comments (in my code I check for both the absence of this item in the json or zero comments in the json to determine when to stop).

You need the "&orderby=published" in the original URL because otherwise the "next" links eventually grow to be too large and cause an error (something in the token the API uses to track which comments you've seen in the default orderby takes a lot of space). Something about the published orderby keeps the "start-token" small, whereas after about 500 comments with the default orderby you will start getting 414 Request URI too long errors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great. I actually had the idea myself sometime, but thought I'd only seen the same urls I had manually queried. Will try when I have the time, which is unfortunately not in the nearest future. Chapeau in advance anyway!